# Extending a finite alternating sum of Riemann Zeta functions

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation, summation-method

Let us define a function

$$f(k) = (-1)^{k+1}\left(1 - \sum_{j=2}^k (-1)^j \zeta(j)\right)$$

for positive integers $k\ge 2$ and, $f(1)=1$ by definition, and $\zeta$ is the Riemann Zeta function.

> Is there a known method to extend this function to real numbers $r>1$
>   (or even $r>0$?).

Comment: I don't think you mean "$f(k) = 1$ by definition."

Comment: The [Ramanujan master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan's_master_theorem) provides a way to analytically extend $\phi(k)$ provided that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \phi(k) \frac{x^k}{k!}$ is entire

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected the definition since I erroneously forgot about $(-1)^k$ factor.

And, yes, it is $f(1)=1$ instead of $f(k)=1$.

Comment: I think I have found it: $$f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)n^x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Not in the way you mean:  in order to extend a function you would want to have it defined on a set with a limit point, but your definition is only on a discrete subset of $\Bbb R$, i.e. a set of natural numbers. Even if you found an extension function, there is no guarantee of uniqueness, since the identity theorem requires a set with a limit point.

If you mean just **any** choice, yeah, that's easy, it's in textbooks:   See Theorem 15.13 in Rudin: Real and Complex Analysis for example.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you are right; there is no guarantee of uniqueness, but I think about at least one extension that agrees on this discrete subset.

Comment: @Jakim see my edit. This is a classical fact available in textbooks.

Comment: Thank you! I will read that.